# Good pair of earmuffs for meditation

Tags: meditation-practicalities, practice

I am looking for a pair of earmuffs to wear while meditating that are effective at reducing noise and comfortable to wear for at least 2 hours. Does anyone have any recommendations of brands that they have actually used?

**Note**: I would like to preemptively state that I am in no way interested in any answer that has to do with noticing my aversion to noise or doing vipassana; anything along these lines does not answer my question and will be down-voted.

Comment: Is there are certain price range you are looking for?

Comment: @Lanka, I would ideally like to pay about $30 USD but if someone has used more expensive ones that they thought were excellent I would want to hear about that as well.

Comment: Earplugs are no option? You'll get plenty of those for 30$.

Comment: @Dawnkeeper, more expensive in the long run. 200 pairs for $30 might last half a year.

Answer (score 3):

I don't find earmuffs or ear plugs effective enough for blocking sounds so I use earphones and white noise. I'm not pushing these particularly but this is what I use for blocking noise while mediating. I've bought these [Sennheiser ear canal head phones](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Sennheiser-MM-30i-Ear-Canal-Headset/dp/B004HD4L2E/ref=sr_1_2?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1446380415&sr=1-2&keywords=sennheiser%20earphones%20in%20ear) and I play white noise through them via this [android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tmsoft.whitenoise.full&hl=en). That pretty much blocks all sound out and I don't find the white noise distracting during meditation. The ear phones also have the advantage of being comfortable enough to sleep in so if you suffer from insomnia or snoring bedfellows then it can be a godsend.

It's not the cheapest solution but it does work for me. There are cheaper in ear head phone such [as these](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B003S3L2DK?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o06_s00) but i don't find these as comfortable to sleep in but they do work fine for meditation so that would cheapen this up. Also there is a free version of the [white noise app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tmsoft.whitenoise.lite&hl=en) which would make it even less expensive but I'm a believer in paying for software if I like it even if the free version is almost as good (which it is). I don't know versions for other phones but there are also [white noise cds](http://www.amazon.co.uk/White-Noise-Tinnitus-Relaxation-Masking/dp/B003F8K7D4/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1446381004&sr=8-7&keywords=white%20noise%20cd) as well if you don't have access to a smart phone.

Hope that helps

Comment: When I have my Etymotic ear canal heaphones in with some sort of noise playing, I'm functionally deaf to the outside world. The ones that look like foam ear plugs that people working with extremely loud equipment are best.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I purchased Clear Armor 34db Highest NRR professional earmuffs online and have been happy with them. They block noise very well but it took me a little bit to get used to them comfort-wise for long periods. I can definitely sit for an hour without any serious discomfort.

Comment: Can you hear your breathing and heartbeat? I find that distracting when I have ear covers on (like the ones used on a rifle range, I used them with loud power tools). It makes me feel like an astronaut in a bad movie. I guess it would assist in "focusing on the breath"!

Comment: I have not noticed either (-: